# Trying to get wifi working on brand new Raspbian installation

Tags: raspbian, wifi, raspbian-wheezy

I just installed Raspbian Wheezy (2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian.img) on my Raspberry Pi, connected it to my AirPort with an ethernet cable and booted it with this wifi dongle (Sitecom N300) inserted:
[image: Sitecom N300 stick]

As you can see from the [output of lsusb and dmesg](https://gist.github.com/SamusAranX/9743919), this dongle is using the RTL8191S chipset, which, as I'm told, *should* be supported in this version of Raspbian. However, there's no wlan* entry in iwconfig's output:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

`firmware-realtek` was already installed, so what am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure the USB device is powered up? What if you try `lsusb` is it there?

Comment: It is indeed there, it's listed as "Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0df6:006c Sitecom Europe B.V." in the Gist linked above.

Comment: FWIW, the kernel version is 3.10.33.

Comment: I just tried using the dongle with a powered USB hub, but the problem persists.

Comment: I also have some problems with WiFi, bad connection when its at a distance, where my other devices work fine. Which version of the Pi do you have? I have the version 1.0, from the very first batches and experience some other problems that shouldn't be there. Try another USB WiFi if you got one? Or can borrow one, like realtek or something

Comment: did you find your device's driver in lsmod?

Comment: This question is almost a year old now. I've since trashed the Wifi stick and bought a new Raspberry Pi. And no, I never got this stick working.

Comment: @PeterW. Sorry about it. I saw this question in the unanswered list. And just to let you know; that problem can be solved by compiling backport drivers to your kernel version. I had similar problem with RTL devices.

Answer (score -2):

You should check if wlan0 is mentioned in `/etc/network/interfaces` file

```
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```